# How can I change the header info of "from"? when using ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using ActionMailer. It's working fine.
But, I've noticed that the owner is clearly stated in header of email sent.

Just like this

```
Received: (from ftpuser@localhost)
```

What is it reffered to?
Indeed, some of my rails files's are ftpuser and rest are root.
How should it be?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example and I hope that this will help, in your app/mailers/notifications_mailer.rb you can set default email address.

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "noreply@yourdomain.net"
  default :to => "info@yourdomain.net"

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(:subject => "[Message Confirmation] #{message.subject}")
  end

end
```

Also check you config/environments directory. Mailers can also be configured there.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't mean that. I wanted to know how to change `Received: (from ftpuser@localhost)` in received email's header. This is probably the owner name of certain file...